# VMware vSphere cant connect to esxi

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I can not connect with the vCenter, the message is:

> vSphere Client could not connect to vcenter. An unknown connection
>   error occurred. (The client could not send a complete request to the
>   server. (The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error
>   occurred on a send.))

[image: Error Screenshot]

> [        :startup :W: 1] 2018-06-04 12:12:40.876  Log for vSphere
>   Client Launcher, pid=16304, version=6.0.0, build=build-5112508,
>   option=release [        :Error   :W: 1] 2018-06-04 12:12:40.898 
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException: ניסיון לבצע פעולה לא מורשית.    ב-
>   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
>   ב-  Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.SetValue(String name, Object value,
>   RegistryValueKind valueKind)    ב- 
>   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.SetValue(String name, Object value)    ב- 
>   VpxClient.Program.RegisterClientMimeExtension() [        :Failed t:P:
>   3] 2018-06-04 12:13:06.906  System.Net.WebException: ההתקשרות הבסיסית
>   נסגרה: שגיאה בלתי צפויה אירעה ב- send. Server stack trace:     ב- 
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>   ...    ב-  System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebDownload.GetResponse() 
>   System.IO.IOException: האימות נכשל מאחר שהצד המרוחק סגר את זרם
>   התעבורה. ...    ב-  System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean
>   async)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [        :Error   :P: 3]
>   2018-06-04 12:13:06.909  possible failure processing clients.xml
>   System.Net.WebException: The client could not send a complete request
>   to the server. (ההתקשרות הבסיסית נסגרה: שגיאה בלתי צפויה אירעה ב-
>   send.)    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebQuery.LocalizeWebException(WebException
>   exception)    ב-  VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebQuery.Request(String
>   url, Nullable`1 timeoutSecs)    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.ClientsXml.ParseXml(Int32 timeoutSecs)
>
>   ב-  VpxClient.Login.ClientsXmlLoader.TrySinglePort(ClientsXml
>   clientXml, Exception& activeError)  System.Net.WebException: ההתקשרות
>   הבסיסית נסגרה: שגיאה בלתי צפויה אירעה ב- send. Server stack trace:
>
>   ב-  System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   ...    ב-  System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebDownload.GetResponse()    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebDownload.get_ResponseStream()    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebQuery.Request(String url, Nullable`1
>   timeoutSecs)  System.IO.IOException: האימות נכשל מאחר שהצד המרוחק סגר
>   את זרם התעבורה. ...    ב- 
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [        :Error   :M: 1]
>   2018-06-04 12:13:07.015  Error retrieving clients.xml Exception
>   already logged, summary: System.Net.WebException:The client could not
>   send a complete request to the server. (ההתקשרות הבסיסית נסגרה: שגיאה
>   בלתי צפויה אירעה ב- send.) [        :Failed t:P: 3] 2018-06-04
>   12:16:42.385  System.Net.WebException: ההתקשרות הבסיסית נסגרה: שגיאה
>   בלתי צפויה אירעה ב- send. Server stack trace:     ב- 
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>   ...    ב-  System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebDownload.GetResponse() 
>   System.IO.IOException: האימות נכשל מאחר שהצד המרוחק סגר את זרם
>   התעבורה. ...    ב-  System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean
>   async)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [        :Error   :P: 3]
>   2018-06-04 12:16:42.385  possible failure processing clients.xml
>   System.Net.WebException: The client could not send a complete request
>   to the server. (ההתקשרות הבסיסית נסגרה: שגיאה בלתי צפויה אירעה ב-
>   send.)    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebQuery.LocalizeWebException(WebException
>   exception)    ב-  VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebQuery.Request(String
>   url, Nullable`1 timeoutSecs)    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.ClientsXml.ParseXml(Int32 timeoutSecs)
>
>   ב-  VpxClient.Login.ClientsXmlLoader.TrySinglePort(ClientsXml
>   clientXml, Exception& activeError)  System.Net.WebException: ההתקשרות
>   הבסיסית נסגרה: שגיאה בלתי צפויה אירעה ב- send. Server stack trace:
>
>   ב-  System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   ...    ב-  System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebDownload.GetResponse()    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebDownload.get_ResponseStream()    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebQuery.Request(String url, Nullable`1
>   timeoutSecs)  System.IO.IOException: האימות נכשל מאחר שהצד המרוחק סגר
>   את זרם התעבורה. ...    ב- 
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [        :Error   :M: 1]
>   2018-06-04 12:16:42.385  Error retrieving clients.xml Exception
>   already logged, summary: System.Net.WebException:The client could not
>   send a complete request to the server. (ההתקשרות הבסיסית נסגרה: שגיאה
>   בלתי צפויה אירעה ב- send.) [        :Failed t:P: 3] 2018-06-04
>   12:17:55.481  System.Net.WebException: ההתקשרות הבסיסית נסגרה: שגיאה
>   בלתי צפויה אירעה ב- send. Server stack trace:     ב- 
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>   ...    ב-  System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebDownload.GetResponse() 
>   System.IO.IOException: האימות נכשל מאחר שהצד המרוחק סגר את זרם
>   התעבורה. ...    ב-  System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean
>   async)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [        :Error   :P: 3]
>   2018-06-04 12:17:55.481  possible failure processing clients.xml
>   System.Net.WebException: The client could not send a complete request
>   to the server. (ההתקשרות הבסיסית נסגרה: שגיאה בלתי צפויה אירעה ב-
>   send.)    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebQuery.LocalizeWebException(WebException
>   exception)    ב-  VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebQuery.Request(String
>   url, Nullable`1 timeoutSecs)    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.ClientsXml.ParseXml(Int32 timeoutSecs)
>
>   ב-  VpxClient.Login.ClientsXmlLoader.TrySinglePort(ClientsXml
>   clientXml, Exception& activeError)  System.Net.WebException: ההתקשרות
>   הבסיסית נסגרה: שגיאה בלתי צפויה אירעה ב- send. Server stack trace:
>
>   ב-  System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   ...    ב-  System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebDownload.GetResponse()    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebDownload.get_ResponseStream()    ב- 
>   VirtualInfrastructure.Utils.WebQuery.Request(String url, Nullable`1
>   timeoutSecs)  System.IO.IOException: האימות נכשל מאחר שהצד המרוחק סגר
>   את זרם התעבורה. ...    ב- 
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace --- [        :Error   :M: 1]
>   2018-06-04 12:17:55.481  Error retrieving clients.xml Exception
>   already logged, summary: System.Net.WebException:The client could not
>   send a complete request to the server. (ההתקשרות הבסיסית נסגרה: שגיאה
>   בלתי צפויה אירעה ב- send.)

Comment: Have you seen and tried the [answers in this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/342863/vmware-vsphere-client-cannot-connect)?

Comment: I seen. It's didn't help me, this soultion for Windows XP. I have Windows 10

Comment: There are 5 answers and only one of them relate to XP. With the given information this is pure guesswork. You could at least add [error messages from the log files](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1021806) to your question.

Comment: I added error messages from the log files. maybe mcafee block it? how can i check and open ?

Comment: A timeout usually points to a firewall issue. In rare cases a routing problem is also a possibility.

Comment: If the ESX host has multiple network interfaces wrong load balancing configuration could also be a problem. You can test this easily by temporarily removing all but one network cable.

Comment: I have installed ESXi 6.7, but when I install ESXi 6.5 it's start to work.

Comment: Which log file has all those errors?